# Copy files from docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have pem files to use in a lots of containers, however i would like to store this file into a unique volume call keys.

I create the volume:

```
docker run -v /data --name keys busybox
```

And add the files there:

```
docker cp JWT_PRIVATE_KEY.pem keys:/data/
```

Now, when a build the services whom need those files a want to copy them from keys:data to my /api workdir.

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  my_api:
    container_name: my_api
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    volumes:
      - keys:/data
    networks:
      - my-network
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  keys:

networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

and this is my DockerFile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /api

COPY package.json /api

RUN yarn install

COPY . /api 

RUN yarn build

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /

EXPOSE 5555

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like a TLS key and certificate that exist outside of Docker space, it will generally be easier to inject it into the container using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) than a named volume.

```yaml
volumes:
  # this references a local directory holding the keys
  - ./keys:/data
```

In the setup you show above, you have a *container* named `keys`, with an anonymous volume mounted on `/data`, but this is separate from the volume with the Compose name of `keys` (and with a `docker volume ls` name that will be something like `api_keys`, starting with the name of the current directory).

If you really need to use a named volume here, probably the easiest way to copy data into it is to [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) a temporary container:

```
docker-compose run \
  -v $PWD:/keys \
  my_api \
  cp /keys/* /data
```

This should inherit the `volumes:` from the `docker-compose.yml` file (so mounting the volume on `/data`), but also adds a bind-mount from the host system.  In that temporary container you copy the files from the host bind mount into the named volume mount, and then they'll persist.

A named-volume setup makes more sense if you're using something like Let's Encrypt where the certificates can be obtained and managed entirely within Docker space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but docker-compose run was not enough =/.
What a need is when I build my DockerFile, Docker copy files from the volume I created to the workdir "/api". If the keys was added inside my project, everything works fine, because the path will be "/api/mykey.pem". But I can't have those keys inside my project, also a lot of container will need to use theses keys too, so, it will be great to have in one place only.